I am getting a compile error: target not supported when trying to compile Solana hello world smart contract
So I'm trying to compile my first Solana smart contract. It's this hello world smart contract:
https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld
Here is my rustc and cargo version:
candid@DESKTOP-5D7VSM9:~/example-helloworld/src/program-rust$ rustc --version
rustc 1.77.2 (25ef9e3d8 2024-04-09)
candid@DESKTOP-5D7VSM9:~/example-helloworld/src/program-rust$ cargo --version
cargo 1.77.2 (e52e36006 2024-03-26)

But here's what happens when I try to compile it:
candid@DESKTOP-5D7VSM9:~/example-helloworld$ npm run build:program-rust

> helloworld@0.0.1 build:program-rust
> cargo build-bpf --manifest-path=./src/program-rust/Cargo.toml --bpf-out-dir=dist/program

   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.81
   Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.12
   Compiling serde v1.0.198
   Compiling version_check v0.9.4
   Compiling typenum v1.17.0
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling syn v1.0.109
   Compiling crunchy v0.2.2
   Compiling semver v1.0.22
   Compiling subtle v2.4.1
   Compiling crossbeam-utils v0.8.19
   Compiling getrandom v0.1.16
   Compiling libc v0.2.153
   Compiling generic-array v0.14.7
   Compiling wasm-bindgen-shared v0.2.92
   Compiling rustc_version v0.4.0
   Compiling rand_core v0.5.1
   Compiling rayon-core v1.12.1
   Compiling quote v1.0.36
   Compiling syn v2.0.60
   Compiling crossbeam-epoch v0.9.18
   Compiling ahash v0.7.8
   Compiling getrandom v0.2.14
error: target is not supported, for more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets
   --> src/lib.rs:357:9
    |
357 | /         compile_error!("target is not supported, for more information see: \
358 | |                         https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets");
    | |________________________________________________________________________^

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
   --> src/lib.rs:408:9
    |
408 |         imp::getrandom_inner(dest)?;
    |         ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
error: could not compile `getrandom` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
Error: Function _ZN15crossbeam_epoch5guard5Guard5flush17h1d1abe609d5edef4E Stack offset of 4112 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 16 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN15crossbeam_epoch8internal6Global7collect17h6342580b0a7115e4E Stack offset of 4152 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 56 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN15crossbeam_epoch8internal5Local5defer17h479e1780ab35f17aE Stack offset of 4176 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 80 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN15crossbeam_epoch8internal5Local8finalize17h1aa606e306161c72E Stack offset of 4104 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 8 bytes, please minimize large stack variables

I am doing this on WSL2 Ubuntu. The build process is failing because some functions in the crossbeam-epoch crate are using more stack space than is allowed for the target platform.
Any ideas on how to fix this? This is a smart contract I am attempting to build from Solana's own "start building" guides on their official site.

This example is really old unfortunately. I would follow what the README says and instead look at https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/local-rust-hello-world
If you really want to get it to work with the new tools however, you can remove the old Cargo.lock file and update the Cargo.toml to the following:
[package]
name = "solana-bpf-helloworld"
version = "0.0.1"
description = "Example template program written in Rust"
authors = ["Solana Maintainers <maintainers@solana.com>"]
repository = "https://github.com/solana-labs/solana"
license = "Apache-2.0"
homepage = "https://solana.com/"
edition = "2021"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []

[dependencies]
borsh = "0.9.3"
borsh-derive = "0.10.0"
solana-program = "1.10.35"

[dev-dependencies]
solana-program-test = "1.10.35"
solana-sdk = "1.10.35"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]

I was able to get this to build with the newest tools. The changes are to use rust edition 2021, get rid of the tildes ~ to pick up the newest version, and to remove the "name" under the [lib].

I got it to compile! Thanks for the assist!
